# Java ArrayList Interface Type

Tags: java, arraylist

I have many classes that implement a common interface. I use a definition like Array List  mytypes, and add objects of that type to the ArrayList. Now i want to use contains method of the ArrayList class to see if this List contains a class i am adding.

If I implement `hashcode` and `equals` on the classes will the contains method know if a certain object already is in the ArrayList or not?

Comment: That depends on the `ArrayList` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList.contains` won't use `hashCode`, but it will use `equals`, [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

(This won't check whether "this class" is already in the list - it will check whether *an equal object* is in the list.)

Comment: But The type of the ArrayList is an Interface. Will the JVM call the equals method on the class that implements the Interface ????

Comment: @user365019: Yes, just as it's documented.

Answer (score 2):

from [`List.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

So basically `hashCode()` is not relevant here, only `equals()`

**EDIT**: [better explicit then implicit], as mentioned in comments by @aiobee, `equals()` still needs to be overriden - according to the contract - but it will not have effect on the value returned by `contains()`

Comment: hashCode should still, according to the contract, be overridden as the OP says.

Comment: @aioobe: yes, it does, I fully agree on this - but it is not relevant to the return value of `contains()`. Anyway, I added it to the answer, since it is indeed woths mentioning explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing hashCode is not useful for that purpose but it is a goog practice to override both equals and hashCode simultaneously.

Yes, it will work, that is the purpose of the contains method.